# How To Make MaterialUI Mini-Varient Drawer Reponsive

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I'm currently working on trying close (not hide) MaterialUI's [Mini Varient Drawer](https://mui.com/components/drawers/#mini-variant-drawer) on small screens, however all the methods I've tried, from an assortment of "fixes", seem a bit "hackish" to me.

I'm currently working with the [example code here](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/mui-org/material-ui/v5.2.1/docs/src/pages/components/drawers/MiniDrawer.js).

It seems to me that this component should have this functionality built in, however even the example demo does not allow for this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think [useMediaQuery](https://mui.com/components/use-media-query/) is fit for this.

```
import useMediaQuery from "@mui/material/useMediaQuery";
import { useTheme } from "@mui/material/styles";
import { useEffect } from "react";

export default function Example() {
  const theme = useTheme();
  const isSmallScreen = useMediaQuery(theme.breakpoints.down("sm"));

  useEffect(() => {
    if (isSmallScreen) {
      setOpen(false);
    }
  }, [isSmallScreen]);
  
  return (<>...</>);
};
```

Comment: Excellent answer! Works perfectly and not 'hackish' at all!

Answer (score 1):

I used this code to change it.

```
const [size] = useState(window.innerWidth || 0);

  useEffect(() => {
        if (size < 992) {
            setOpen(false);
        }
    }, [size])
```

Comment: but you are right bcs there is not a default setting for that in MUI.

Comment: Thanks Samira! I have added an answer based on your comment.

Answer (score 1):

Based on @Samira's comment, I have updated my code to the below fix. This still seems 'hackish' to me, but it works:

```
  const getWidth = () => window.innerWidth 
  || document.documentElement.clientWidth 
  || document.body.clientWidth;


  useEffect(() => {
    const resizeListener = () => {
      if(getWidth() < 992) {
        handleDrawerClose();
      }else{
        handleDrawerOpen();
      }
    };
    window.addEventListener('resize', resizeListener);
    window.addEventListener('load', resizeListener);
    return () => {
      window.removeEventListener('resize', resizeListener);
      window.addEventListener('load', resizeListener);
    }
  }, []);
```